# Rectangles are not colliding?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision, rectangles

**Player Class**

```
public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor {
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
    private float speed = 500;
    public Rectangle rectangle;
    public Player(Sprite sprite){
        super(sprite);
        this.rectangle = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        super.draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    public void update(float delta) {
        rectangle = new Rectangle(getX() + velocity.x * delta,0,rectangle.getWidth(),rectangle.getWidth());
        setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);
    }
}
```

**PlayScreen Class**

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private Player player;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private TiledMap map;
    private Rectangle rightRectangle, leftRectangle, playerRectangle;
    //private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();
        renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
        player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
        renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

        //shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        //shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        //shapeRenderer.rect(
        //  player.getX() + player.velocity.x * delta, 0, 
        //  player.rectangle.getWidth(), player.rectangle.getHeight());
        //shapeRenderer.end();
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        map = new TiledMap();
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        //shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")));
        rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
        leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);

        boolean wallLeft = leftRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);
        boolean wallRight = rightRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);

        if(wallLeft){
            System.out.println("wallLeft Overlap");
            player.velocity.x = 0;
        }
        else if(wallRight){
            System.out.println("wallRight Overlap");
            player.velocity.x = 0;
        }
        player.setPosition(
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f - player.getWidth()/2f,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f - player.getHeight()/2f 
                - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5f);
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to be colliding correctly. The `rightRectangle` and `leftRectangle` are my screen side bounds. When I use the `shapeRenderer`, it produces the `ShapeRendered` rectangle and it will follow my player around. However, I believe that my `player.rectangle` is not moving at all for some reason, resulting in it not colliding with my side bounds. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);
```

A Rectangle is defined as Rectangle(x, y, width, height).  It looks like you are trying to define it incorrectly as Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2).  In the above, you have created two rectangles of 0 width.

Comment: I realize that, but it should still work even though it is zero (I think I tested this out a while back, where the collision worked). If I were to change the width to 1 or even 0.0001 and run the program, it will always be overlapping the leftRectangle but will not stop the sprite from moving (if the width was zero, it doesn't overlap but the sprite doesn't stop moving).